# jQuery CSS selector question

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Whats wrong with this CSS selector i'm using in jQuery? Trying to select all tr's within a table of ID "itable" without a class of "mod" where its possible for multiple classes to be on each tr.

```
if($('#itable tr:not[class~=mod]').length == 0){
    //something
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($('#itable tr:not(.mod)')[0]){
    //something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#itable tr:not(.mod)
```

Answer (score 1):

youre using the :not selector the wrong way http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector

```
if($('#itable > tr:not(.mod)').length == 0){
    //something
}
```